# Need help getting this to work. Trying to save a product to the database, the controller receives the info but doesn't save?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Hi i'm using a form to create a new product and send the info to the controller and save it into the database, the form does send the data because I can see it when I do a Log inside the controller and the info is there, I don't understand why it's not being saved into the database?

In this example the data I've added to the product is minimal but there could be more like prices and countries, along with the stuff inside the store function like tags and sizes.

This is the complete store function in the controller

```
public function store(ProductSaveRequest $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $product = new Product;
        $product->fill($request->all());
        $file = $request->file('image');

        if ($file) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $filename = Uuid::uuid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('img/products', $filename);
            $product->image = 'img/products/' . $filename;
        }

        $product->save();
        Log::info($product);

        if (!empty($request->get('prices'))) {
            $prices = array_map(function ($item) use ($product) {
                $item['product_id'] = $product->id;
                return $item;
            }, $request->get('prices'));
            CountryProduct::insert($prices);
        }

        if ($request->has('tags')) {
            $product->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));
        }

        if ($request->has('sizes')) {
            $product->sizes()->sync($request->get('sizes'));
        }

        if ($request->has('categories')) {
            $productCategories = [];
            foreach ($request->get('categories') as $item) {
                if (key_exists('category_name', $item)) {
                    $category = Category::where('name', $item['category_name'])
                        ->first();
                } else if (key_exists('category_id', $item)) {
                    $category = Category::findOrFail($item['category_id']);
                }

                if (empty($category)) {
                    $category = new Category;
                    $category->name = $item['category_name'];
                }

                $category->type = $item['type'];
                $category->save();

                if (!empty($item['fields'])) {
                    foreach ($item['fields'] as $fieldItem) {
                        if (key_exists('field_name', $fieldItem)) {
                            $field = Field::where('name', $fieldItem['field_name'])
                                ->first();
                        } else if (key_exists('field_id', $fieldItem)) {
                            $field = Field::findOrFail($fieldItem['field_id']);
                        }

                        if (empty($field)) {
                            $field = new Field;
                            $field->name = $fieldItem['field_name'];
                            $field->category_id = $category->id;
                        }

                        $field->save();

                        $productCategories[] = [
                            "field_id" => $field->id,
                            "category_id" => $category->id,
                            "product_id" => $product->id,
                            "value" => $fieldItem['value']
                        ];
                    }
                }

                if (count($productCategories) > 0) {
                    ProductField::insert($productCategories);
                }

                ExportationFactor::insert($product);
            }

            $product->save();
            DB::commit();
            return $product;
        }

    }
```

This is the Log.info

```
local.INFO: {"discount":"1","code":"123","sku":"123","description_spanish":"123","description_english":"123","brand_id":"2","id":591}
```

The current output is that I get a success action and it says it has been successfully added but when I go look it's not there.

Comment: you are inserting values in multiple tables. what about the other tables?? do they have values after the whole store function runs?? and why have you used `$product->save()` twice??

Comment: that was my attempt to get it to save, I added the second $product->save

Comment: you don't need to use it twice. you can use `update` if you change anything after saving an object. in this case you are not changing or updating anything after saving it. so remove the second save function. and what about the other tables??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon what about them? what do you mean?

Comment: you are inserting values in other tables too. do values insert in other tables??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I don't think so, nothing is getting added

Comment: then maybe something is wrong with any insertion and the transaction function does not commit anything.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon how can i check where its failing? of which part is not inserting?

Comment: try out my answer. if that does not work, try out without transaction function.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `commit` method outside the last `if` condition.

```
public function store(ProductSaveRequest $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $product = new Product;
        $product->fill($request->all());
        $file = $request->file('image');

        if ($file) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $filename = Uuid::uuid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move('img/products', $filename);
            $product->image = 'img/products/' . $filename;
        }

        $product->save();
        Log::info($product);

        if (!empty($request->get('prices'))) {
            $prices = array_map(function ($item) use ($product) {
                $item['product_id'] = $product->id;
                return $item;
            }, $request->get('prices'));
            CountryProduct::insert($prices);
        }

        if ($request->has('tags')) {
            $product->tags()->sync($request->get('tags'));
        }

        if ($request->has('sizes')) {
            $product->sizes()->sync($request->get('sizes'));
        }

        if ($request->has('categories')) {
            $productCategories = [];
            foreach ($request->get('categories') as $item) {
                if (key_exists('category_name', $item)) {
                    $category = Category::where('name', $item['category_name'])
                        ->first();
                } else if (key_exists('category_id', $item)) {
                    $category = Category::findOrFail($item['category_id']);
                }

                if (empty($category)) {
                    $category = new Category;
                    $category->name = $item['category_name'];
                }

                $category->type = $item['type'];
                $category->save();

                if (!empty($item['fields'])) {
                    foreach ($item['fields'] as $fieldItem) {
                        if (key_exists('field_name', $fieldItem)) {
                            $field = Field::where('name', $fieldItem['field_name'])
                                ->first();
                        } else if (key_exists('field_id', $fieldItem)) {
                            $field = Field::findOrFail($fieldItem['field_id']);
                        }

                        if (empty($field)) {
                            $field = new Field;
                            $field->name = $fieldItem['field_name'];
                            $field->category_id = $category->id;
                        }

                        $field->save();

                        $productCategories[] = [
                            "field_id" => $field->id,
                            "category_id" => $category->id,
                            "product_id" => $product->id,
                            "value" => $fieldItem['value']
                        ];
                    }
                }

                if (count($productCategories) > 0) {
                    ProductField::insert($productCategories);
                }

                ExportationFactor::insert($product);
            }

        }

        DB::commit();
        return $product;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of the method, you begin a database transaction.

But you only commit the database transaction

```
if ($request->has('categories')) {
```

Comment: so what should i do instead?